# Setup different path for fish shell temporally

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, fish

User libraries are normally in `/usr/local/lib`. However I want to build some third party libraries in for example `/Users/user/Public/lib`.

I only want to do it during my testing. Is there a elegant way to do this?

I'm using fish shell for OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the library path is selected using the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, you could do

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/user/Public/lib fish
```